# Is Vishnu one of the names of Vamana?

Tags: vamana

What are the names of Vamana other than **Aditya**, **Upendra**, **TriVikrama** and **IndrAnuja**. Specifically, is his one of the names **Vishnu**?

If not, then is there any other Aditya with the name Vishnu as **Bhagavad Gita 10.21** says that there is one Aditya named Vishnu? Also, **Adi Parva** of Mahabharata mentions that Vishnu is youngest among Adityas which raises some possibility that he is Vamana.

Comment: TriVikrama is another name (after he took on the expansive form)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Vishnu is one of the names of Vamana. This is mentioned by Sri Madhusudhana Saraswati in his commentary on the Bhagavad gita, for verse 10.21.

> Gita moola shloka
>
> आदित्यानामहं विष्णुर्ज्योतिषां रविरंशुमान्।
>
> मरीचिर्मरुतामस्मि नक्षत्राणामहं शशी।।10.21।।
>
> ādityānāmahaṅ viṣṇurjyōtiṣāṅ raviraṅśumān.
>
> marīcirmarutāmasmi nakṣatrāṇāmahaṅ śaśī৷৷10.21৷৷
>
> Translation: Among Adityas I am Vishnu....

For this verse, Sri Madhusudhana gives one of the interpretations of the word "Vishnu" as the Vamana avatar.

> Part of the sanskrit commentary by Sri Madhusudhana
>
> ....आदित्यानां द्वादशानां मध्ये विष्णुर्विष्णुनामादित्योऽहं? *वामनावतारो* वा।...
>
> ādityānāṅ dvādaśānāṅ madhyē viṣṇurviṣṇunāmādityō.haṅ? *vāmanāvatārō* vā.
>
> Translation essence: Among 12 Adityas, I am the Aditya named Vishnu or Vamana incarnation...

---

Sri Vallabhacharya, Swami Ramsukhdas, Sri Neelkanth and Sri Dhanpati also  [translate](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=21&htrskd=1&hcrskd=1&scval=1&scms=1&scneel=1&scdhan=1) the BG10.21 verse आदित्यानामहं विष्णु as **Vamana**.

Comment: This is an English language site. You should add full translation and English transliteration when the main shloka which is the heart of the answer is in Devanagari. Not many users can read and understand Sanskrit or devanagari.

Comment: This is added now.