# What is difference between Trinity Vishnu, Shiva and 12 Aditya Vishnu and 11Rudra Shiva?

Tags: vishnu, shiva

We have 12 Adityas of whom one is Vishnu. And 11 Rudras of whom one is Shankara.

Are they Vishnu and Shiva counted in Trinity? If not, who are they? Are they related to trinity gods?

Answer (score 1):

Vishnu among Adityas is actually Lord Vishnu's incarnation Vamana. Sri Vallabhacharya, Sri Madhusudhana Saraswati, Swami Ramsukhdas, Sri Neelkanth and Sri Dhanpati translate the **BG10.21 verse आदित्यानामहं विष्णु** as Vamana. More details can be found [here](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=21&htrskd=1&hcrskd=1&scval=1&scms=1&scneel=1&scdhan=1) and in the below post:

[Is Vishnu one of the names of Vamana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23587/is-vishnu-one-of-the-names-of-vamana/32494#32494)

---

Rudra is also an incarnation of Lord Shiva as the son of Lord Brahma, this is discussed in below posts:

[Are Lord Shiva and Lord Shankar two different deities?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/are-lord-shiva-and-lord-shankar-two-different-deities/2294#2294)

[Linguistic connection between Rudra and Marudgaṇa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27782/linguistic-connection-between-rudra-and-marudga%e1%b9%87a/27790#27790)

[Who are the parents of Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24224/who-are-the-parents-of-lord-shiva/24323#24323)